# Return Null after calling .getElementById in react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am new to react and HTML5 and I try to create a  canvas that has 3 images one under the other. I am using react for that.

I create a function that renders an App component. This function returns something like this

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas className="canvas1" id="canvas1" width="70" height="300"></canvas>
      {Game()}
    </div>
  );
```

The Game is the function that(lives inside the App function) I want to preload the images and do some initial changes to the canvas element. The implementation is something like this:

```
function Game() {
    var c1 = document.getElementById("canvas1").getContext("2d");
    //Here the code will do changes to the canvas element


    this.draw(true);
  }
```

The problem that I am facing is that the code above does not compile. I get error that getElementById returns Null.

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

I can not understand what is going on. I suspect that something has not loaded correctly and there is nothing at c1 when I call getElementById  but I can not find out how to check this possibility.

What can I do to start debugging it?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to operate on dom directly consider using refs, below is hooks implementation.

```js
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = ref.current
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <canvas className="canvas1" ref={ref} width="70" height="300"></canvas>
      {Game()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to image
eg:

```
 class Canvas extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <canvas ref="canvas" width={640} height={425} />
            <img ref="image" src={cheese} className="hidden" />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    export default Canvas
```